# Best content type for managing projects info

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, custom-list, configuration

I want to add a new list that stores project info which are:-

- Project name.
- Project number
- Start date
- Status

So I want to create a new site CT to store this info, but I'm not sure which is the best parent site CT that is most related to this?

If I want to create a new list and change its CT to be the new “Project CT” , then which list best satisfy my needs or would it will be better to create a new custom list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of this information, I would create the content type from the Item content type, then apply it to a Custom list. Any other content type you base it off of gives you a bunch of unnecessary fields.

I could also see this being a document set if you are wanting to store artifacts, but if it is merely for tracking projects, then a custom list and a content type based off of item is what I would do.

Comment: but one problem i will be facing is that the item content type has a filed named "title" and it is a required field,, but in my case i do not want to have a field named title .. can you advice ?

Comment: and also i can only hide the "title" from the new CT but i can not remove it, and when i try adding a new project using the quick edit, i will keep receiving an error that some info is missing (as the title is required). and to fix this i need to chnage the title to be optional at the list level.. seems a very long process .. can you adivce ?

Comment: In your created content type, change the name Title to Project Name.

Comment: but i can not chnage the column name at the CT level , at the CT level i can only chnage if the column is required, optional or hidden., in this case i need to modify the built-in column name to be "project name" instead of title .. which is not recommended , as i should never modify built-in columns..

Comment: Then mark it hidden, and make sure it is marked hidden on the list